# Why does a "SAMSUNG_Android" network service keep appearing?

Tags: macos, network, preferences, system-settings

I recently noticed a strange service in the Network preferences called "SAMSUNG_Android", which seems to be configured as a modem:

[image]
[image]

I don't have an Android or Samsung device and I've never plugged one into my computer. The only things I've recently plugged in are an iPhone, iPad, and Sony camera.

I noticed this yesterday, and deleted the service. **Today, it's back!**

Where could this be coming from, and how can I make it go away for good?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks like someone near you has a Samsung Android device with the ability to create a personal WiFi hotspot.

Your computer WiFi is able to detect this so will add it to your list of available networks. You might try disabling the prompt to join new networks if you don't want your Mac polling for open and closed hotspots and cluttering up your network connection profile if you cannot isolate or control for the source of this hotspot.

Comment: It's not on the list of Wi-Fi networks, but it's an entirely new network service. Can this still happen?

Comment: Yes, It can also happen if you go into an area with a new network service. Just go kncking on your neighbours doors.

Answer (score 1):

I began noticing the "SAMSUNG_Android" preference (via a message from a pop-up dialog box every time I connected my Samsung Galaxy S II to charge on the USB cable) shortly after I'd installed Kies on my MacBook.

I've just Un-installed Kies gracefully by using the uninstaller and no longer receive the pop-ups when attaching my phone to USB, nor does the Samsung network appear in my network preferences.

Answer (score 0):

Did you by any chance install the Android SDK? Apparently, installing it create this network interface.